# Get the url from a popup on click event not displaying href on DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am parsing a page using an iframe. 
I need the href element from a link. This link only display hashed data though. On click, the link trigger a popup, which has the right URL I am trying to grab. 
How to get it without leaving my main iframe page, and stopping my javascript ?

I grabbed the link using Jquery dom to print a console.log(link.click());
The popup is blocked and it only return me some hashed data.

```
<div class="blEntry website" data-ahref="PFnGSCJIiuCWJcVt84pIaQtipEnV1zS0pIaQaVMSpa1EVTVEEJc" data-column="2" data-trackingkey="URL_EATERY" data-eventname="bl_contact_website" onclick="ta.prwidgets.call('handlers.onWebLinkClicked', event, this)">
<span class="ui_icon laptop"></span>
<span>Site Web</span>
</div>
```

Simulating a click open the popup, which has the URL. I don't figured out how to get the URL when the popup try to open.

Comment: Does the widget you are using allow access to unhashed data? That's because I can see that the widget script is likely performing the unhashing and calling `window.open` (or setting `window.location`) internally. If the widget has no API available, your only option is to figure out how to unhash the URL yourself.

Comment: No. I have no access to the unhashed data and there is no API. Though, i have the right URL in the popup. What would be the best way to get it and bring it back in my script ?

Comment: If the popup window that opens is not on the same origin, you can't get the URL because you will not have access to the `window` object of the popup.

Comment: Oh well, too bad for me. Thank you !